# How to Get Asp.net Application Instance Name on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, instance

How to get application instance name on IIS for performance monitor counters?
something like this:

```
_LM_W3SVC_16_ROOT
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I suppose it doesn't work, as far as I got the question, it's necessary to get the instance name by third party tools, outside the iis application. For example I need to do it in my performance monitoring application.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, use:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationID
```